# Pass URL string from javascript to WCF Service

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service which I want to pass URL strings to. However, whenever it encounters a `'%'` or `'/'` character it falls over.

Example from javascript, this works

```
$.post("http://localhost:15286/Service1.svc/Submit/thor");
```

But neither of these do:

```
$.post("http://localhost:15286/Service1.svc/Submit/http://www.google.com");
$.post("http://localhost:15286/Service1.svc/Submit/http:%");
```

I have a breakpoint in my service and it doesn't even get hit for the last two examples.

I'm new to WCF services so I might just be making a rookie mistake.

WCF Service

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Submit/{imageURL}")]
    [OperationContract]
    string Submit(string imageURL);
}


public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string Submit(string imageURL)
    {
        return String.Format("Thanks, you sent me '{0}'.", imageURL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try a test with argument `th%20or` and let us know the results? I would expect that to resolve to `th<space>or` server-side.

Comment: @RB th%20or worked. So it isn't the % that is the problem. Based on that I tried encodeURIComponent("http://www.google.com") which resolves to http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com which failed. It doesn't like the %3A, the %F2 or the '.' characters :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try encoding the last part of the URL with the [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) JavaScript function:

```
var parameter = encodeURIComponent("http://www.google.com")
var url = "http://localhost:15286/Service1.svc/Submit/" + parameter 
$.post(url);
```

However, you might still get the same error due to **WCF not correctly parsing some URL encoded characters**. This seems to be [a bug in WCF](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/413312/wcf-uritemplate-strips-some-urlencoded-characters-from-bound-path-segment), to which there are a couple of known workarounds:

- Pass the encoded URL parameter as a *query string parameter*
- Configure *how URI should be parsed* through the [<schemeSettings>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656539.aspx) configuration element available in .NET 4.0

You could start by passing the encoded URL as a query string parameter and see if it works. Here's an example:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Submit?url={imageURL}")]
    [OperationContract]
    string Submit(string imageURL);
}
```

and on the client:

```
var parameter = encodeURIComponent("http://www.google.com")
var url = "http://localhost:15286/Service1.svc/Submit?url=" + parameter 
$.post(url);
```

Comment: That will encode the whole URL. He only needs to encode the argument :)

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me the same result. I think the problem is on the web service side of things possibly?

Comment: Encoding the argument gives the same result. As encoding it will add '%' signs and the web service doesn't seem to like them  either :(

Comment: @user914082 Did you try using `encodeURIComponent` as in my answer? That will encode the `:` and `/` characters, which I'm sure will fix your problem.

Comment: @user914082 Could you post the code for your Web Service implementation? We might be able to spot the problem there.

Comment: Yep I tried your suggestion. encodeURIComponent converts the '/' characters to %2F. However, the WCF service doesn't seem to like % characters either.

If I call the service with "test" it works. If I call the service with "test%" it doesn't. :(

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio I've updated the first post with the WCF service code. Let me know if you want the webconfig as well.

Comment: Yay, changing it to use a query string parameter did the job. Thanks everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) function to correctly encode your parameter, e.g:

```
$.post("http://localhost:15286/Service1.svc/Submit/" + 
       encodeURIComponent("http://www.google.com"));
```

Note that the encodeURI function will not encode the `/` or `:` character.